# HTML mobile button show/hide after few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have for my mobilesite some buttons.

```
<div class="menubottom" id="menumobile">
    <div >
        <div class="mobilebutton displaynone" id="mobilebuttonLeft" style="float:left;" onclick="swipeRight();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="mobilebutton" id="mobilebuttonRight" style="float:right;" onclick="swipeLeft()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

now i want them to disappear if a amount of time with no TouchInput passes away.
And if i Touch again on the display the buttons should be appear again. 
I have jquery and jquery mobile installed but i cant find a good resolution for my problem. Did you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now i want them to disappear if a amount of time with no TouchInput
>   passes away

You can do `setTimeout` which will *hide the menu* after *2 seconds*

```
function hideMenu(){
    setTimeout( function(){
      $ ( "#menumobile" ).hide();
    }, 2000);
}
```

To make it reappear again on click, just bind a `touchend` event

```
$(document).on( "touchend click", function(){
  $ ( "#menumobile" ).show();
  hideMenu(); //hide again after 2 seconds
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use touchstart and touchend event for hiding show mobilebutton

> settimeout of 3s for hide button after touchend

```
$("body").on('touchstart mousedown',function (e){
    $('.mobilebutton').show();
});
$("body").on('touchend',function (e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.mobilebutton').hide(); 
    }, 3000);
});
```